# importing with variable file name

Tags: excel

each day I import some files into a master spreadsheet. The file has a time stamp random 8 digit number generated so I cant anticipate the file name. I previously had ???????? in place of the code which was working. After some IT changes it doesn't work now, we just changed drives and I updated the location all is fine if I add the sequence instead of ???'s

How can I make it so that I can mimic the effect I had before where ?????? worked - most of the file name is unique and can be estimated _ ( with dates etc.) but its just the last 8 digits.

```
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
  Dim Wb2 As Workbook
  Dim filepath As String

  filepath = Sheets("control").Cells(1, 5).Value

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius _
          Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & _
           "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(76765435).xls")
  'current acc FMCM
```

... workaround for the this part

```
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius_
         Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & _
         "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(76765435).xls")
```

how can I edit this to search for just FMCM ?

```
Sub ubstransi()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("ubs trans").Select

' This section could have an unexpected result because it is not clear which cells are you clearing

Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim filepath As String

filepath = Sheets("control").Cells(1, 5).Value

Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(76882269).xls")
'FMCM *** NOTE that there is no wildcard in your code...



Wb1.Sheets("Cash Movement").Range("A1:x100").Copy
Windows("MEMF RECS2.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("ubs trans").Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

Sheets("UBS trans").Select
    Range("AD2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
         "=IF(AND((IF(OR(RC[-22]=""FOREX TRADE SPOT"",RC[-22]=""Transfer"",LEFT(RC[-22],5)=""UBSFX"",LEFT(RC[-22],6)=""UBS FX""),""FX"",0)=""FX""),RC[-21]=control!R2C3),""FX"",0)"
   Range("AD2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AD100").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False


Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & "\5446890_FMSH_" & filepath & "_(76885899).xls")
'FMSH *** NOTE that there is no wildcard in your code...
Wb2.Sheets("Securities Holdings").Range("A1:X100").Copy

Windows("MEMF RECS2.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("UBS AM POS").Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

Wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False



Windows("MEMF RECS2.xlsm").Activate

Sheets("BBGCASH").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    Dim datename As String
    Dim datename2 As String
    datename = Sheets("control").Cells(1, 5).Value
    datename2 = Sheets("control").Cells(2, 5).Value

    ' This instruction can not be handle as it is not setting to any var.

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & datename & "\f3576cshdump2.ext." & datename2 & ".1.txt"

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("MEMF RECS2.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("BBGCASH").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


Sheets("control").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: `Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(????????).xls")` should work...

Comment: Thanks this was working then we moved to a new drive and now it wont recognise it. And it only works iff I type the digits in and not the ???????.  so I know its not the link address in the code.

Comment: Did you try `"\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(*.xls"`?`. Wildcards doesn´t depends on the drive.

Comment: so with the ???????? the error message shows its looking for the file with ?'s . so its not using it as any number

Comment: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(*.xls") and tried with closed (*) - basic knowledge here

Comment: No. In fact, there should not be any error. `*` is acting replacing a string, no a character, so you don't need to close parent.

Comment: I could just match the first 30 letters of the string or even a search on just FMCM ,or by a left(30,)=xx OR search for "FMCM" in the string - will that work with defining work books?

Comment: Should work, but keeping wildcard characters

Comment: can you please advise how to add this, please?

Comment: You should use instead of `"C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(76765435).xls"` ... `"C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(*.xls"`

Comment: Hi David - get a runtime error saying it could not find the file. So annoying. Can you please advise how I can add this only not look up the last part of the file ?

Comment: Added wildcards tried to enter my new code but it wouldn't let me. but Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(*.xls") and I get the error advising cant find the file

Comment: I am doubting... which one is the number you need to replace by wildcards? 5446890? or 76765435?

Comment: 76765435    / 
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\" & filepath & "\5446890_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(*.xls")
'FMCM *** NOTE that there is no wildcard in your code...

Comment: Ok, so it is NOT the 7 digit numbers you mention before, so it is a 8 digit numbers...

Comment: sorry I meant to say the 8 digits at the end. the last part of the file name is what changes to a random code ...(76765435).xls") updated my question as see it said 7 then 8 - just 8

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub Open_Workboook()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim MyPath As String, MyFile As String
Dim filepath as String

filepath = Sheets("control").Cells(1, 5).Value

MyPath = "C:\Users\damian_MCP\Mobius Capital Partners\Mobius _
    Capital Partners Team Site - Documents\Operations\FTP\"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(76765435).xls")

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFile)
    MyName = WB.Name
    If MsgBox("Is this the file you want to open?" & vbTab & MyName, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        GoTo continue
    Else
        WB.Close
    End If
        MyFile = Dir()
Loop
Exit Sub

continue:
WB.Close
MsgBox "File Find... and close " & MyName

End Sub
```

It will work, later just adapt.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks this doesn't work, I don't get the error box, I think the best way it to just look up on the first x numbers/letter of the string , is that possible? I have other things I do with the workbook once its opened, mainly copy and paste into my file.

Comment: Ok, step by step. Instead of `MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(76765435).xls")` try `MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls")`. Please tell me about the result.

Comment: I just tried  with the MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(76765435).xls")  and got an error message - I forgot to add my file path which is basically each the folder is the date in YYYYMMDD format. i got an error saying couldn't find the file, even though i updated the digits to match the file

Comment: I edited the comment, try again. Use this procedure to see what is wrong.

Comment: I already check your code and clean a little bit... Check my comments. Anyhow, the procedure I gave it is generic. If you get that one to work, we will adapt to your case.

Comment: thanks, I did try the wildcards but just copied in the full code as I previously had so you could see my full initial code. thanks will try the comments and let you know.

Comment: Ok, step by step. Instead of MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*_FMCM_" & filepath & "_(76765435).xls") try MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls"). Please tell me about the result. - will try this but adj the wildcard to the end,